# Curve Modifier: Align object to the center of the Path?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a curved path, which is animated from curved to flat. My idea is to have a rectangle in the middle of this path, so it bends flat when animated.

The Simple Deform modifier doesn't give the effect I want, because it bends on the sides only.

If my rectangle is the same size as the Path, it kinda works, but since is right aligned it shows more gap on the left.

I would like to use the Curve modifier and set my object to stay in the middle. Is this possible? Can I somehow select one point from the Path and set it as origin?

I'm using Blender 2.83.

[image]

As you can see, here's the animation. It should align from the center.

[image]

Comment: so once you've given it the Curve modifier, if you move it towards the center of the curve, it should work as expected, non?

Comment: It should, but for some reason it doesn't. I added a gif showing how it looks. I manually added to the center, but it bends towards a side.

Comment: maybe you should choose another way to do it, for example give your object a Surface Deform modifier, with a subdivided plane as Target, and give 2 shapekeys to your plane: flat and bent, use Proportional Editing for the bent version. Or even do it directly with your object?

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. Surface Deform might work! I will give it a try. 
Directly modifying the object with shape-keys didn't look natural. 

I will give a try with Surface Deform. Thank you so far!